# Spotfire Over Function

Tags: function, spotfire

I'd like to know why the following OVER function causes my "complete" items to still display as "pending"

Step 1 Calculated Column:

```
case  
WHEN ([Job]="A") AND ([Sample]="A") AND ([Test]="A") THEN "Complete"
Else "Pending"
END
```

Step 2 Calculated Column:

```
Max(
case  
when [LIMS Pending_Complete]~="LIMS Pending" then 
     "LIMS Pending" 
when [LIMS Pending_Complete]~="LIMS Complete" then 
     "LIMS Complete"
end) OVER ([Batch Number])
```

[Link to desired data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoikG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you are looking for was incorrectly filtered, where the calculation below is for the entire data set, not based on your filtered values.

When using the following custom expressions for the pending complete column and the over column, the results come out correctly.

**PorC Column**

```
case  
WHEN ([Job]="A") AND ([Sample]="A") AND ([Test]="A") THEN "Complete"
Else "Pending"
END
```

**Over Column**

```
Max(
case  
when [PorC]~="Pending" then 
     "LIMS Pending" 
when [PorC]~="Complete" then 
     "LIMS Complete"
end) OVER ([Batch])
```

**To apply the over function to filtered values**
case
when ([Column 1]="Label 1") or ([Column 1]="Label 2") then Max([PoC]) over ([Batch])
end

Answer (score 1):

@JQA - As I understand your question, I think you are trying to show the status which is most repeating in 'Pending_Complete' column per Batch number. If that is the case, below over expression should get you the result.

```
MostCommon([Pending_Complete]) over ([Batch Number])
```

**Table:**
[image]

If this is not the solution you are looking for, please let me know so that I could refine it.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm not looking for most common. When a batch number has all "complete" in the pending_complete column, then the over result should show complete over all rows with that batch number. When a batch number has at least one pending row, then the over results should show pending for all rows of that batch. See image in original post for reference. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @JQA- Thanks for clarifying! Also, thanks for posting your solution. Please go ahead and accept your answer.